# difference between like '%%%var%%' and '%var%'

Tags: wp-query, query

What is the difference (if any) between:

```
$ids = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key='_product_attributes' AND meta_value LIKE '%%%s%%';", $code));
```

and

```
$ids = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key='_product_attributes' AND meta_value LIKE '%s%';", $code));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firtly, in SQL the `%` symbol is a ["wildcard operator"](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp). When used in a `LIKE` statement, it means "0 or more characters". So `LIKE 'Hello%'` *means any string beginning with `Hello`, including just `Hello`*. While `LIKE '%Hello%'` means *any string that contains `Hello`, either at the beginning, middle, or end*.

`$wpdb->prepare()` on the other hand uses the `%` symbol to support placeholders, with `%d` and `%s`. It allows you to safely insert a variable into a query.

So the problem is that the `%` has two different meanings, which will give you trouble if you try to `$wpdb->prepare()` a `LIKE` query.

The solution is to 'escape' the `%` symbol by using the character twice, like `%%`. This tells `$wpdb->prepare()` that the `%` symbol is a *literal* `%` symbol, and not part of a placeholder. This is how you use the `%` symbol in a `LIKE` query with a placeholder.

So in your first example:

```
LIKE '%%%s%%'
```

If `$code` is `Hello`, then the resulting SQL statement is:

```
LIKE '%Hello%'
```

Because `%s` has been substituted with `$code`, and the double `%%` have been interpreted as `%`, leaving us with a valid `LIKE` statement for *any string that contains `Hello`, either at the beginning, middle, or end*.

Your other example on the other hand:

```
LIKE '%s%'
```

Would not work. Because `%s` will be substituted with `$code`, but a stray `%` is remaining that will appear as a broken placeholder. If you only want to find strings beginning with `$code`, you would need to use:

```
LIKE '%s%%'
```

Which would give you:

```
LIKE 'Hello%'
```